# How this Odoo website route will work

Tags: python, routes, odoo, odoo-9

I am learning website module of Odoo 9 and want to know the format of route expression. I am aware about the regex but could not get it completely. Take a look to this :-

```py
class WebsiteBlog(http.Controller):
    _blog_post_per_page = 20
    _post_comment_per_page = 10

    # codes 

    @http.route([
        '/blog/<model("blog.blog"):blog>',
        '/blog/<model("blog.blog"):blog>/page/<int:page>',
        '/blog/<model("blog.blog"):blog>/tag/<string:tag>',
        '/blog/<model("blog.blog"):blog>/tag/<string:tag>/page/<int:page>',
    ], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
    def blog(self, blog=None, tag=None, page=1, **opt):
        print 123
        # etc
```

You can find this code on [Git: Website Blog Module](https://github.com/maestrano/odoo/blob/2abc65859998b8602f613a0ee965b3b6fb0d1724/addons/website_blog/controllers/main.py#L85)

I want to understand these expression. I can understand that this function will be executed if any one of these four URL will be requested by the browser and **blog**, **tag** and **page** are the variables but what is the meaning of this **model(blog.blog)** here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It defines that you are passing a value in URL is the record of the model blog.blog.
Ex.
your url like this..

```
localhost:8069/blog/3
```

Then in the controller you will get the record of model blog.blog which is having id = 3.

Comment: What if 3 in localhost:8069/blog/3 will not a record of the related model . Will it throw any error ?

Comment: Yes. it will throw an error. because that record not found. so, it will be 404.

Comment: Is it helpfull?